# Add a message to the $error MessageBag

Tags: php, laravel

This is Laravel 4.2

Laravel will make the $error MessageBag available to views. This can be populated with flash messages in the *previous* page by redirecting `->withErrors()`. That is fine if you are redirecting to a new page.

```
return Redirect::route('my_route')->withErrors($validator);
```

I am generating some errors in the controller, not validating a form, and want to put those messages into the $errors MessageBag that Laravel automatically passes into the views. But how? The MessageBag is *somewhere*, but how do I get to it, and how do I add some messages to it to display in the *current* page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like I can inject messages when the view is created.

My controller passes the required view, with the data it collects, to the content of the page template like this:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('my.view', $view_data);
```

Errors can be passed in like this:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('my.view', $view_data)->withErrors($my_errors);
```

where $my_errors can be null or array() (for "no additional errors"), an array of text messages, or a MessageBag.

My outer page template then just picks up the messages if they exist, and displays them at the top of the page:

```
@if ( $errors->count() > 0 )
    ...An error occured...
    @foreach( $errors->all() as $message )
        ...{{ $message }}...
    @endforeach
@endif
```

(with markup where appropriate)

Comment: The ability to pass an array of text messages in, may just be an artefact of the way I am displaying the messages. I think sticking to a MessageBag would be more consistent.

Comment: I do dislike accepting my own answers, but this solved my problem, once I had discovered that the View class has a `withErrors()` method that allows messages to be injected into $errors (they get merged with any that Laravel already pulls on from any previous page redirect).

Answer (score 5):

I have done that with some custom validations. What you need is something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class MyCustomValidator
{
    protected $errors = array();

    protected $messageBag;

    public function __construct(MessageBag $messageBag)
    {
        $this->messageBag = $messageBag;
    }

    public function setErrors($errors = array())
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($errors); $i++) {
            $this->messageBag->add($i, $errors[$i]);
        }

        $this->errors = $this->messageBag;
    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors->all();
    }
}
```

In your controller you have to call something like

```
$validator = new MyCustomValidator();
$validator->getErrors();
```

You can access the full documentation for the MessageBag [in the docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html).

Comment: So does Laravel automatically inject the global MessageBag into the validator? So this is just a trick to get at that MessageBag?

Comment: When you do something like this `->withErrors($validator)` you are telling laravel that your view will receive a variable `$errors` with the content of `$validator`. Typically, `$validator` is `$validation->messages()` which returns a object of the class `\Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` (in this context the variable `$validation` is an instance of the class `Illuminate\Validation\Factory`, the same as the facade `Validator`). In reality, you are passing the `MessageBag` to the view and it is not injected automatically.

Comment: Thanks. It is `->withErrors()` when creating the view that I was not aware of. My messages aren't coming from any kind of validator, so presumably I can just create a MessageBay, add messages, and pass that in.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful, and is bookmarked for the future. However, it is probably tangential to problem I was specifically trying to solve, as I wasn't dealing with any kind of Laravel validator, custom or not. The error was being returned by a call to an external payment gateway, so I just needed a simple way to push that message to the [current] page.

Comment: The way I see it, a validation must perform a data validation (be  it in a database or a logic one). In your case, it seems that you have a logic validation. It really depends on how you have structured your code, but I would create that validation within a validation class instead of creating it directly in the controller.

Comment: Yes, I do accept and agree with that. In this case, all the local validation has taken place and passed, then a call is made to a remote system with the data. That remote system may still return errors for various reasons, rejecting the data. Some reasons may require the user to change some of the data they submitted, some reasons may be out of our control and the user just needs to try again later. But the point is, we have gone past all the validation we can perform in the application. What the remote system throws back at is, needs to be presented to the user, so they can decide what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5

```
$validator = .......

$validator->after(function($validator) {
    .....               
    $validator->errors()->add('tagName', 'Error message');
    .....
});
```

Mind that the anonimous function is in the scope of the class, not in that
of the function where you use it. If you need the value of some variable from the outside world it must be a class variable!

Answer (score 1):

Be late but another solution to add custom message in error message bag is:

**Controller**

```php
$rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|exists:users,email|email|max:32',
        'password' => 'required|max:20'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);


    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    $validateUser = new user();
    $users = $validateUser::where('email', $email)->get();
    if($users->isEmpty()){
        $validator->getMessageBag()->add('email', 'Invalid Email Address');    
        return redirect('home')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $data = $user->showAdminData();
        if($user->role_id!=1){
            $validator->getMessageBag()->add('email', 'Unauthorised access');
        }
        if(Crypt::decrypt($user->password)!==$password){
            $validator->getMessageBag()->add('password', 'Invalid Password');
        }
    }
    return redirect('home')->withErrors($validator);
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I see `$errors->first(...)` in *so* many places and examples, as though the first error in any list of errors (in context) is the only one that is important. Why has it persisted in Laravel for so many years? Just feels lazy to me. Anyway, thanks for the input, but I'm not sure it tackles the original question - it is just an example of how errors are flashed across pages in normal form validation. Or am I missing something?